Convolution with Sum of Divisors

Prove $\sigma\left(n\right)=\sum_{m|n}^{ }\phi\left(m\right)\cdot d\left(\frac{n}{m}\right)$

I understand that $\sigma = id * 1$ (id is identity), $id = \phi * 1$, so $\sigma = (\phi * 1) * 1 = \phi * d)$
However, while I understand each individual relation, I am having trouble visualizing them together. Using an alternative approach, I tried:
Let $n=p_{1}^{\alpha_{1}}p_{2}^{\alpha_{2}}...p^{\alpha_{k}}$
$$\sigma\left(n\right)=\sum_{m|n}^{ }\phi\left(m\right)\cdot d\left(\frac{n}{m}\right)=\sum_{0\le\beta_{i}\le\alpha_{i}\ \ \forall1\le i\le k}^{ }\phi\left(p_{1}^{\beta_{1}}p_{2}^{\beta_{2}}...p_{k}^{\beta_{k}}\right)d\left(p_{1}^{\alpha_{1}-\beta_{1}}p_{2}^{\alpha_{2}-\beta_{2}}...p_{k}^{\alpha_{k}-\beta_{k}}\right)$$
But now, I am stuck and don't know how to proceed to get the final form. I know each function is multiplicative, but I do not know how to continue. Can someone help me with this visualization?

Do you know that $\sigma$ is a multiplicative function and that the convolution of multiplicative functions is again multiplicative? If so, then an easy way to demonstrate a convolution identity like this is to show that it holds when $n$ is a prime power. Then multiplicativity of both sides shows that both functions are equal for arbitrary natural number inputs.

I think I see how to continue now. Thanks!
